# JAXB Unmarshalling @XmlAnyElement

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2

I have created three JAXB class : `Home , Person , Animal` . Java Class 
Home have variable `List<Object> any` that may contain Person and/or Animal instance .

```
    public class Home {
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected List<Object> any;
    //setter getter also implemented
    }
@XmlRootElement(name = "Person")                            // Edited
    public class Person {
        protected String name; //setter getter also implemented
     } 
@XmlRootElement(name = "Animal")                             // Edited
    public class Animal {
       protected String name; //setter getter also implemented
     }
```

---

/* **After Unmarshalling** */

```
 Home home ;

                for(Object obj : home .getAny()){
                    if(obj instanceof Person ){
                        Person  person = (Person )obj;
                        // .........
                    }else if(obj instanceof Animal ){
                        Animal animal = (Animal )obj;
                        // .........
                    }
                }
```

I need to achieve `Person or Animal` object saved in `"Home.any" List` variable but content of `"Home.any" List` is instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl` instead of `Animal or Person` .

So is there a way to achieve `Animal or Person` instance that is saved in xml in `"Home.any" List`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `@XmlRootElement` on the classes you want to appear as instances in the field/property you have annotated with `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`.

### Java Model

**Home**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Home {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;

    //setter getter also implemented
}
```

**Person**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
public class Person {
```

}

**Animal**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Animal")
public class Animal {

}
```

### Demo Code

**input.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Person/>
    <Animal/>
    <Person/>
</root>
```

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Home.class, Person.class, Animal.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum20329510/input.xml");
        Home home = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml, Home.class).getValue();

        for(Object object : home.any) {
            System.out.println(object.getClass());
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
class forum20329510.Person
class forum20329510.Animal
class forum20329510.Person
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html

Comment: I have already added @XmlRootElement(name = "Person") and @XmlRootElement(name = "Animal") also added entry in ObjectFactory.java .

Comment: @userG - How are you creating your `JAXBContext` and is it aware of all your classes?

Comment: According to your post , i think ; there is a problem with JAXBContext Declaration JAXBContext.newInstance(Home.class) .

Comment: I have already defined both @XmlRootElement and entry in ObjectFactory.java . Is i have to define only one of them ?

Comment: JAXBContext.newInstance(Home.class,Person.class,Animal.class) , @XmlRootElement already added and entry from ObjectFactory.java commented but still not resolved .

Comment: @userG - I have updated my answer with a complete code example.

Comment: Thanks @Blaise for your guidance , tested your code working fine as stated . I am working on netbeans plugin and using api org.netbeans.modules.xml.jaxb.api , i am still facing this problem and for temporary solution , passing dom.Element object to unmarshall method again to retrieve jaxb object . (I have also seen JAXBContext.typeMap  Person & Animal both reference exist .)

Comment: What about java.lang.* classes like String? Any tips on how to unmarshall a List<String>?